# How to profile dagger 2 tree init

Tags: dagger-2

We have a big DI tree.
Now we want to find types that takes a huge time to create instance.
Create time is composition of: di dependency resolution, instance creation and instance init.
I can't find a tool which can trace di tree init.
Is it possible to collect this information?